# React, setState warning for mounted/unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component I am using to load my images progressively for my app which has been working great for me. When I use it on a page to load images, though, I am seeing an error:

> warning.js:35 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Multiple times - looks like once for each image called. It does not seem to be effecting anything seriously as the image components still work. I am wondering how to get rid of this error though, I cannot figure out how.

So here is my component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

require('./progressive-image.scss');

export default class ProgressiveImage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      image: props.smallImg
    };

    this.loadImage = this.loadImage.bind(this);
    this.onLoad = this.onLoad.bind(this);
    this.onError = this.onError.bind(this);
    this.image = undefined;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { largeImg } = this.props;
    this.loadImage(largeImg);
  }

  onError(err) {
    console.warn('Error loading progressive image :', err);
  }

  onLoad() {
    this.setState({
      loaded: true,
      image: this.image.src
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
    const { largeImg, smallImg } = nextProps;

    if (largeImg !== this.props.largeImg) {
      this.setState({ loaded: false, image: smallImg }, () => {
        this.loadImage(largeImg);
      });
    }
  }


  loadImage(src) {
    if (this.image) {
      this.image.onload = null;
      this.image.onerror = null;
    }

    const image = new Image();
    this.image = image;
    image.onload = this.onLoad;
    image.onerror = this.onError;
    image.src = src;
  }

  render() {
    const imgStyle = { 'paddingBottom': this.props.heightRatio };
    const { imgAlt, imgTitle } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={`progressive-placeholder ${this.state.loaded ? 'loaded' : ''}`}>
        {this.state.loaded &&
          <img
            alt={imgAlt}
            className={`loaded`}
            src={this.state.image}
            title={imgTitle}
             />
        }
        <img className={`img-small ${!this.state.loaded ? 'loaded' : ''}`} src={this.state.image} alt="placeholder image for loading"/>
        <div style={imgStyle} ></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ProgressiveImage.displayName = 'ProgressiveImage';

ProgressiveImage.propTypes = {
  bgColor: PropTypes.string,
  heightRatio: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  largeImg: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  smallImg: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  imgAlt: PropTypes.string,
  imgTitle: PropTypes.string,
};
```

So the only time setState is called is when `onLoad`or `componentDidUpdate` is called. My thinking is that because its only called did mount and did update it should not be getting this error. Looking for any insight on how to clean up this error, as it has me puzzled. If any additional info is needed, I am happy to provide.

Comment: can't mutate state on didUpdate, or it will go into an endless loop.

Comment: How did this `componentDidlUpdate` typo get in there?

Comment: @DimitarChristoff is that what's causing the issue then? I tried swapping it to componentWillUpdate, and still am seeing the error.

Comment: Just a note, `Prop-Types` have been moved to their own package and will be removed from the `React` package in future releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your callback in `image.onload` could be called at **any random point**:

```
    image.onload = this.onLoad;
```

Chances are `this.onLoad` is being called while your component is rendering.

The problem is that because `this.onLoad` is called when your external image resource loads then when you are doing `this.setState`, your component could be rendering and **this would cause the error**.

To handle this I would recommend setting the `loaded`/`image` values outside of the local `Component` state and instead `dispatch` it to a global state using something like `redux`.

Comment: I am using redux I will give this a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to solve this with your clues by just not allowing the `loadImage` to fire if the component was not mounted. Thanks again.